# Ошибка mysql.connector в python

Tags: mysql, python

Код

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

sql = """select now();"""

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', database='test', user='root', password='12345')
    if connection.is_connected() : print('Connected to MySQL database')
except Error as e:
    print(e)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
```

Выводит "Connected to MySQL database" и завершается с ошибкой:

```
Connected to MySQL database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 16, in <module>
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Почему и как заставить работать с помощью оператора with?

Answer (score 3):

[Описание причины](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7447369/4248686)
**with** использует методы `__enter__` и `__exit__` и в данном случае у объекта, возвращаемого `cursor()`, нет метода `__exit__`
Т.е. с `with` данную функцию использовать не получится
Используйте простое присвоение

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
```

Comment: У connection есть exit, но тем не менее не работает. Почему?  http://pastebin.com/0bj3VK9e

Comment: @user211049, у connection и cursor отсутствуют необходимые методы [Скрипт для проверки](http://pastebin.com/W9z5xsDR)